# Exponent sum Law in Semigroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

If $G$ is a semigroup (i.e. it is endowed with associative operation), why it is true that $x^{n+m}=x^nx^m$ for any $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$?

I fix $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and then use induction on $m$. If $m=0$, obvious. Suppose the claim true for $m$, what happens for $m+1$? May I write

$$
x^{n+m+1}=x^{n+m}x
$$

and then continue by induction?

Comment: A minor caveat: when you are trying to prove this kind of low-level fact, you really should define what exactly you mean by $x^n$. The argument you cited works if you define $x^{n+1}$ as $x^n\cdot x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your proof is correct. The fact that $x^{N+1}=x^N x$ (along with $x^0 = 1$)is the definition of the exponent notation.

Comment: It might be, but it also might not be. In some books, the definition of $x^N$ for positive $N$ is $\overbrace{x\cdot x\cdots x}^{N\text{ times}}$, in which case the result is immediate by associativity of the operation and basic counting. It's not difficult to translate between the two interpretations, though.

Comment: Yes, but the definition of the dots $\cdots$ is by induction.

Comment: If you mean that the definition of "Count to $N$" is by induction (which could definitely be argued for), then yes, I agree.